# How to override the effect when the function display() is predefined AND change the effect in each element of the array

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have the following code

```js
var bubbles = [];

function setup(){
  createCanvas(600, 400);

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let x = random(width);
  let y = random(height);
  let r = random(10, 50); 
  bubbles.push(new Bubble(x, y, r));
 }
}

function draw(){
  background(0);
  for(let i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++){
    bubbles[i].move();
    bubbles[i].display();
  }
}
//When mouse over any bubbles, I want to call function coverColor()**
function mouseMoved(){
  for(let i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++){
    bubbles[i].coverColor();
  }
}

class Bubble {
  constructor(x, y, r){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;
  }

  //Specify the coordinates of the mouse cursor so that when the mouse over bubbles, the bubble will change color:**
  coverColor() {
    let d = dist( mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
    if (d < this.r){
    fill(102, 102, 255);
    }
  }

  //function display() already had the fill(color)**
  display() {
    stroke(0, 191, 255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(255, 51, 51); //this one**
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r*2);
  }
  move() {
    this.x = this.x + random(1, -1);
    this.y = this.y + random(1, -1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

I am trying to find answers for the following:

1. When I mouse over the bubbles it doesn't change to the new color, I want to `mouseMove()` effective.
2. And when successful to change color, I want to change the color of each bubble independently when mouse over(now its change all the bubbles though I just mouse on one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a attribute to the class `Bubble` which states if the bubble was touched (`this.hit`):

```js
class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y, r){
        // [...]        

        this.hit = false;
    }

    // [...]
```

Set the fill color dependent on the state when you draw the bubble:

```js
class Bubble {
    // [...]

    display() {
        // [...]        

        if (this.hit) {
            fill(102, 102, 255); 
        } else { 
            noFill();
        }
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r*2);
    }
```

Change the state when the mouse hovers over the bubble. Optionally you can reset the state if the mouse "leaves" the bubble:

```
class Bubble {
    // [...]

    coverColor() {
        let d = dist( mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
        if (d < this.r){
            this.hit = true;
        } else {
           // this code would cancel the "hit" state, when the mouse leaves the bubble
           // this.hit = false;
        }
    }

    // [...]
```

See the example:

```js
var bubbles = [];

function setup(){
    createCanvas(600, 400);

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let x = random(width);
        let y = random(height);
        let r = random(10, 50); 
        bubbles.push(new Bubble(x, y, r));
    }
  }

function draw(){
    background(0);
    for(let i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++){
        bubbles[i].move();
        bubbles[i].display();
    }
}

function mouseMoved(){
    for(let i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++){
        bubbles[i].coverColor();
    }
}

class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y, r){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.hit = false;
    }

    coverColor() {
        let d = dist( mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
        if (d < this.r){
            this.hit = true;
        } else {
           // this code would cancel the "hit" state, when the mouse leaves the bubble
           // this.hit = false;
        }
    }

    display() {
        stroke(0, 191, 255);
        strokeWeight(2);
        if (this.hit) {
            fill(102, 102, 255); 
        } else { 
            noFill();
        }
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r*2);
    }
    move() {
        this.x = this.x + random(1, -1);
        this.y = this.y + random(1, -1);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank for your help, although I have a minor thing: If display() have noFill() effect instead of fill(color), then how do I get the same result?

Comment: could you help me for more.

Comment: the idea is: The bubbles have a noFill() from a start, then touching its => change to new color. Maybe, it have another way to do, but have to rewrite the entire code above

Comment: @ChauNgoc I've changed the answer.